# Why `this` property cannot access within function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

### The Problem

I am working on a jQuery plugin. When called with `$.fn.bar()`, the alert() within foo() is not outputting the expected result. Where did I make the mistake?

```
(function($){

  var input;

  var foo = function(){
    alert(this.input); //<-- Not getting the desire input value
  }

  $.fn.bar = function(){

    this.input = "Test";

    alert(this.input); //<-- Output "Test" as expected
    foo(); //<-- Call foo(), expect to alert "Test" as well, but not

  };


}(jQuery));
```

### Solution

You need to pass the context `this` within `bar()` to `foo()` with `foo.call(this)`.

https://jsfiddle.net/clintonlam/de1vz59w/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `.call` the `foo` function with whatever `this` is inside `bar`, so that `bar`'s calling context gets transferred to `foo`:

```js
var foo = function() {
  console.log('foo', this.input);
};
$.fn.bar = function() {
  this.input = "Test";
  console.log('bar', this.input);
  foo.call(this);
};

$().bar();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What should I do, If I want to pass values to foo as well? `foo.call(this, values)`?

Comment: Yep, and have `values` be the first parameter of `foo`